# Effect of gravity on inhabitants floating in the Jupiter atmosphere

Tags: gravity, jupiter

In several science fiction mythologies, humans live in artificial habitats in the Jovian atmosphere (Piers Anthony's "Bio of a Space Tyrant" and Ian M Banks "the Algebraist" for example).

Assuming a given orbital habit is floating in the Jovian atmosphere at some distance from the surface of Jupiter, gravity is affecting its inhabitants.  I guess we should also be assuming that there exists a triple point where all the [inhabitants are not molten jelly](https://what-if.xkcd.com/138/).

Is it accurate to think of the effect of gravity, for the inhabitants of a bubble floating on the Jovian atmosphere, to be similar to that which submariners experience?  I.e., gravity equivalent to the surface of the planet it's floating around?

Comment: @Energizer777 The Jovian surface gravity is just 2.5g.

Comment: Of course the gravity in the outer reaches of Saturn's atmosphere is only slightly above one gee, making it a better choice for setting stories that involve unmodified human colonists. Of course, in the Banks story the humans are only visitors.

Comment: LLlAMnYP, Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The 'bubble capsules' would be moving too slow to cause a reduction in the normal or *support* force, which is possible only when the bubbles are in free-fall, which is not the case since it is mentioned that the bubbles are floating due to their buoyancy in Jupiter's atmosphere.

The inhabitants of the capsule would exert a force on it, which would be balanced by the buoyant force of the atmosphere on the capsule.